# pycharm ide gives syntax error with python 3.10 but code is working fine

Tags: python, pycharm, ide, with-statement, python-3.10

hi I just installed ***windows 11*** and ***python 3.10*** and ***pycharm 2021.2.2***
now when I use python 3.10 in pycharm and use some new features in python 3.10 i get some highlight in my code
but the code is working fine
here is what I'm experiencing :

[image: syntax error highlight in pycharm 2021.2 and python 3.10]

i really don't have any idea to how to fix it
help please

Comment: Python 3.10 was released just yesterday. Do not expect that all introspection of code will work from day 1 (literally). In any case, PyCharm use Python to run the code, so you get no error on running the code, just syntax check is not yet ready for all cases.

Comment: Parenthesized context managers allow for continuation across multiple lines. In your case *with open(...) as a, open(...) as b* on one line will give the same functionality

Comment: This syntax is not yet supported in PyCharm - see the dedicated ticket https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-42200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the parenthesis, and:

```
with open(file = "file1") as file1, open(file="file2") as file2:
    print(file1)
    print(file2)
```

Works for me, p.s. I'm using PyCharm 2021.2.2 Professional Edition on Ubuntu.

Comment: But this is not a solution. Python10 allows us to use the parenthesis, you are just using the old syntax. https://bugs.python.org/issue12782

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Pavel Karateev in the comments, this is a bug in PyCharm, still as of 2022-03-09.

All we can do is vote for and await the resolution of [issue PY-42200](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-42200).